# EDIT - How to copy paste data validation with change in range?

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

So I made a dynamic data validation drop-down list based on the data validation in the cell next to it. The problem is that when I copy this data validation to a 1000 rows I want it to change the range depending on the row. I know it has to be done manually but was wondering if it can be automated?

So basically what I have is that A1 is the service you choose, and then B1 gives you the option to choose the sub-service from the formula I created which is basically

```
=TRANSPOSE(SI(ESTVIDE(Prestations!$C7);;SI(Prestations!$C7='Données'!$B$28;INDIRECT("Depose");SI(Prestations!$C7='Données'!$E$28;INDIRECT("Sols");SI(Prestations!$C7='Données'!$H$28;INDIRECT("Cloisons");SI(Prestations!$C7='Données'!$K$28;INDIRECT("Peinture");SI(Prestations!$C7='Données'!$N$28;INDIRECT("Plafonds");SI(Prestations!$C7='Données'!$Q$28;INDIRECT("Plomberie_CVC");SI(Prestations!$C7='Données'!$T$28;INDIRECT("Autres");SI(Prestations!$C7='Données'!$W$28;INDIRECT("Cas_Specifique");"Prestation n'existe pas"))))))))))
```

The code is in french sorry about that. So basically SI=IF, ESTVIDE=ISBLANK and the ,s are ;s. Prestations!$C7 is the service so basically our "A1" and then enclosed within the INDIRECTS are the named ranges for the sub-services. 'Données'!B28:W28 is basically me comparing the name of the service in the A1 dropdown.

And then I just copy-pasted this over a 1000 rows. So this is basically let's say our E1 and then copied till E1000. In data validation, I just put the range as E1:Z1. I used transpose because otherwise, the data would clash with the copied formulas beneath.

Now what I need is the data validation for A2 onward. Of course, when I copy-paste the data validation it takes the same range E1:Z1. Can it be modified to become E2:Z2, E3:Z3 and so on?

Edit: Here's a link to the document [Prestation_Test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LcNKOU4jUDM3JXAyZzjJxmQC1WH5YTSXmLyq6rRcJXI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hey try again, let me know if it works

Comment: works... unfortunately the problematics you are asking about is solvable only manually (eg setting it up row by row). an alternative would be to look into script world - maybe there are some means how to alter it programmatically

Comment: I see. I will have a look into that. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This can be done in Apps Scripts, but I'm not sure about the question here. What you are trying is to copy the data validation of E1:Z1 to all the rows until E1000:Z1000, right?

Comment: Hey actually no basically in each row I want the data validation to change the range. So basically in the first row I want the data validation to be E1:Z1 and for the second row E2:Z2 and so on

Comment: I'm sorry, as there are several sheets it's not clear what cells need the data validation and where is it coming from. It needs a [rule](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)  that will take a range and use it as data validation for other cells. I would need you to specify: 1- The sheet and range of the rule, and 2- The cells which are going to get the data validation. You mentioned E1:Z1, but in "Prestations" they go form E7 to P7. Thanks.

Comment: Hey sorry. Basically when I tried explaining in the start I kept to simple notations as to not confuse everyone but now that I shared the file I'll explain it. So basically in the sheet called Prestations, D7:D needs data validation. If you go in the sheet Data_Validation you'll see the formula in the column A, and that is what the range is supposed to be for each cell starting from D7 in Prestations. So basically the data validation range for D7 should be 'Data_Validation!'A1:Z1, for D8 ...A2:Z2 and so on. Hope you have a better image of what I'm trying to do now. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out how to do it through Google Apps Script. If anyone comes across a problem like this, I'd like to put the solution out there:

So what I did is that I used the for function to change the row number both for the range to which I had to apply the Data Validation and the range for the Data Validation itself.

```
function DataValidation() {



  for (var rowC = 1; rowC < 994; rowC++) {

    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DV").getRange(rowC, 1, 1, 30);
    var validation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range, true).build();
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(rowC+5, 4).setDataValidation(validation);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

---

### EDIT - Please note that this answer was posted when the question was still tagged with "Excel".

OK. If I understand correctly, one way to do what you want would be to define a dynamic named range, using the current cell row.

Define a named range called "DataValidation" with the formula:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$E:$E,ROW()):INDEX(Sheet1!$Z:$Z,ROW())
```

You will need to change "Sheet1" to be the name of your sheet containing your E1:Z1000 range (it's not clear from your question which sheet it is on).

Then you can enter

```
=DataValidation
```

into the data validation of a cell and drag that cell down. The data validation will then be based on what ever is in columns E to Z of the current row.

---

### EDIT - How to define a named range

1. Go to the "Formulas" ribbon.
2. Click "Name Manager".
3. Click "New".
4. Enter "DataValidation" as the name.
5. Enter the above formula (with the sheet name changed) into the
   "Refers to:" box.
6. Click "OK".
7. Click "Close".

Please see image below:

[image]

Comment: Hey, trying to figure out how to put a formula as a named range? Never did it before perhaps you could guide me? Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the swift response. I am on google sheets however,  can't really figure out how to do this there.

Comment: Oh. Apologies. The question was originally tagged with Excel, and I did not notice that you needed a google sheets solution. Sorry, but I don't think I am familiar enough with google sheets to help.

Comment: That's my bad I apologize. Thank you for your help though!